# GNU Screen split tab

Tags: tabs, split, gnu-screen

I'm looking for a way to split a tab (not all tabs) with GNU Screen.
I currently have one tab per account / application. For an application I would like to see the log and have a bash at the same time.

I tried to create a new instance of screen in this tab but it creates a new tab...

Anyone can help me please ?

PS: What would I like: http://www.imagup.com/data/1168517677.html

To simulate, I created an additional tab

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A good idea when posting questions is to add examples, too: it will be easier for users to answer. I strongly suggest you to post some screenshots, for example.

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello: I think this question contains a lot of useful information already. Also, not sure a screenshot would help here since it relates to a workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the control sequence for `screen` is the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> the current window can be split with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>. Then switch to the new pane with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> and get e.g. window 1 there with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>.

Comment: unfortunately the screen is split for all tabs :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new screen instance within your already existing screen, you can run

```
screen -S SOME-NAME
```

However, please note that such a screen-within-a-screen is difficult to manipulate because you need to escape all <kbd>C-a</kbd> bindings to forward them to the inner screen. For example, sending <kbd>C-a</kbd> to the inner screen is done with <kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, and you can switch between two tabs using <kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>.